# Difference between a function and a stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The two examples below are apparently resulting in the exact same code.

Example 1 (React child):

```
const Child = ({ item: { startedAt, count } }) => (
  <div>
    <div>{startedAt}</div>
    <div>{count}</div>
  </div>
)

const Parent = items => {
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <Child key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Parent
```

Example 2 (function child):

```
const child = ({ id, startedAt, count }) => (
  <div key={id}>
    <div>{startedAt}</div>
    <div>{count}</div>
  </div>
)

const Parent = items => {
  return <div>{items.map(child)}</div>
}

export default Parent
```

Why would one go with example 1, i.e. a React component? Are there any benefits over the function example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, these 2 snippets of code are not completely equivalent:

The first example is creating a new (and unnecessary) function in every render (the one inside `items.map` that creates and returns the `Child` element), which can clutter the garbage collector. Therefore, the second example is not only more concise, it also performs better. So, I personally, would go with the second example.

Also, the second example won't nest an unnecessary call to `React.createElement`. Meaning that the map function will return something like:

```
[
  React.createElement('div', {key: items[0].key},
    React.createElement('div', null, items[0].startedAt),
    React.createElement('div', null, items[0].count)
  ),
  React.createElement('div', {key: items[1].key},
    React.createElement('div', null, items[1].startedAt),
    React.createElement('div', null, items[1].count)
  ),
  ...
]
```

The first example, on the other hand, does something like this:

```
[
  React.createElement(Child, {key: items[0].key}, items[0]),
  React.createElement(Child, {key: items[1].key}, items[1]),
  ...
]
```

It's also worth pointing out that the `child` function of your second example is actually a **stateless functional component** too. Whether you want to consume it calling the function directly or wrapping it though a `React.createElement` call is up to you, in this case I think that it makes more sense to call the function directly.

Answer (score 4):

The both are stateless react components. Your second example has also react child  -**Functional Components** are stateless react components. This is more about code readability and this could be a syntactic sugar to render child components. You can inspect in dev tools as it will show them as `React.CreateElement`.

I would rather go for first example. It gives an clear manifestation there's an child component exists.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The difference is not just about "code readability", the first example is creating new (and unnecessary) functions in every in **every** render, which clutters the garbage collector. The second example is more performant, also I personally find it a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @Josep. but both are react childrens. Right ?

Comment: Sorry @sakhi-mansoor but I honestly don't understand your question.

Comment: I meant both child are react elements.

Comment: Oh, I see, well, then no, I think that you are mistaken. The second example won't create the element of "child", do you know what I mean? So, the second example will have one level less of nested elements for each child.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks for the clarification.